# Change an element of a list of tuples in haskell

Tags: haskell

I have a list of tuples that contain variables and their values. I want to update the value of one specific variable and return the updated list.
I guess it should be something like:

```
updateValue variable val (x:xs) 
      | fst x == variable = snd x = val (update the value somehow)
      | otherwise update variable val xs
```

I have read that there is no such thing like reassign a value in Haskell and also I do not understand how can I update the value and return a new list.

Update: if I have `[(variable, 1), (variable,2), (variable, 4), (variable2, 2)]` and I update the variable to 5, I will get `[(variable, 5), (variable, 5), (variable, 5), (variable2, 2)]`, instead of just `[(variable, 5), (variable2, 2)]`. Is there a way to make this function this way?

Comment: In Haskell you do not *update* variables, you create a new value, and you work with that value. Variables are *immutable*.

Answer (score 3):

What we mean by “changing” a value is normally, returning a *modified copy*. In your case, you would pass the original list as the argument to your function and get the modified one back as the result. The original list stays intact (but if it's not used anywhere else, the garbage collector will quickly delete it).

```
type VarId = String
    
updateValue :: VarId -> a -> [(VarId,a)] -> [(VarId,a)]
updateValue variable val ((v,x):xs) 
      | v==variable  = (v,val) : updateValue variable val xs
      | otherwise    = (v,x) : updateValue variable val xs
```

I highlighted the parts where you also pass back the *unchanged* data.

Alternatively – Haskell *does* have mutable variables, just you need to be explicit and work in a suitable monad. In this case, you could use [mutable vectors](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-0.12.1.2/docs/Data-Vector-Mutable.html) in the [ST monad](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Control-Monad-ST.html):

```
import qualified Data.Vector.Mutable as VM
import Control.Monad.ST

updateValue :: VarId -> a -> VM.MVector s (VarId, a) -> ST s ()
updateValue variable val xs = go 0
 where go i
        | i >= VM.length xs   = return ()
        | otherwise  = do
           VM.modify xs
                     (\(v,x) -> (v, if v==variable then val else x))
                     i
           go $ i+1
```

Comment: Thanks! May I ask a question about your solution, please? So, in this line `v==variable  = val : updateValue variable val xs` shouldn't it be something like `(v, val) : updateValue variable val xs` ?

Comment: I have tried both variants, but none of them seems to work(

Comment: I took the liberty to patch the code with a minor fix. Hopefully now it type checks.

Comment: Unfortunately, I still get type mismatch error. What can be the reason?

Comment: @qwerty the current version (as updated by chi) typechecks for me. What problems are you getting?

Comment: @leftaroundabout  I get "Non-exhaustive patterns in function"

Comment: Actually, if I am trying `updateValue "variable" 3 [("variable1", 4), ("variable", 2)]` I get => `[("variable1", 4), ("variable", 2)`*** Exception...: Non-exhaustive patterns in function...

Comment: Also, I have just realized that if I have several similar records, it will just update them, right? I mean if I have `[(variable, 1), (variable,2), (variable, 4)]` and I update the variable to 5, I will get `[(variable, 5), (variable, 5), (variable, 5)]`, instead of just `(variable, 5)]`. Is there a way to improve the function?

Comment: @qwerty that's not a type error, it's just a missing pattern. Note that you only deal with the case of `x:xs`, i.e. lists that have at least one element (the head).

Comment: @leftaroundabout oh I see, thanks for your help and explanation!!! I really have some big problems with understanding Haskell tbh.